# How to create this SOAP XML request?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, soap

we are using SAOP clients for a while now without a problem. But now we are facing the following challenge and I can't find the answer. We need to send the following XML structure:

```
<Cards>
 <CardDetails>
  <Name>string</Name>
  <Address>string</String>
 </CardDetails>
 <CardDetails>
  <Name>string</Name>
  <Address>string</String>
 </CardDetails>
</Cards>
```

As you van see we need two instances of 'CardDetails'. Creating a PHP array will only allow me to send 1.

```
$data = array(
    'Cards' => array(
        'CardDetails' => array(
            'Name' => 'test name',
            'Address' => 'test address'
        ),
        'CardDetails' => array(
            'Name' => 'second test name',
            'Address' => 'second test address'
        )
    )
));
```

Of course, only the second address will be used. But what would be the solution to make this work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use php dom to create xml from an array , here is a good example of it http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/

Answer (score 0):

And what function/class are you using to turn array to xml?

Try this structure:

```
$data = array(
    'Cards' => array(
        'CardDetails' => array(
            array(
                'Name' => 'test name',
                'Address' => 'test address'
            ),
            array(
                'Name' => 'second test name',
                'Address' => 'second test address'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

If this doesn't work and you can modify serializing function, just check if current key is numerical. If it is, use parent key name for tag.